# Example class for Boost boyer_moore search corpusIter type?

Tags: c++, boost, case-insensitive, boyer-moore

I've successfully used:

```
boost::algorithm::boyer_moore_search<const char *,const char *>( haystack, haystack_end, needle, needle_end )
```

to look for a needle in a haystack.  Now I'd like to use BM_search to do a case-insensitive search for the needle.  Since my haystack is giant, my plan is to convert the needle to lower case and have the haystack iterator treat the haystack characters as a special class whose compare function converts alphabetics to lower case before comparing.  However, I haven't been able to express this correctly.  I'm trying:

```
class casechar {
    public:
      char ch;
      // other stuff...it's not right, but I don't think the compiler is even getting this far
} ;

class caseiter : public std::iterator<random_access_iterator_tag,casechar> {
      const casechar *ptr;
    public:
      // various iterator functions, but not enough of them, apparently!
} ;

boost::algorithm::boyer_moore_search<const caseiter,const char *>( HaYsTaCk, HaYsTaCk_EnD, needle, needle_end );
```

The compiler (g++ on OSX) is complaining about an attempt to instantiate hash<casechar>, I guess for some BM internal thing.  I'm lost in a maze of template<twisty_passages,all_different>.  Could I impose on someone for a bit of direction?  I suspect I just need to provide certain implementations in casechar and/or caseiter, but I don't know which ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The first problem you will run into](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/algorithm/searching/boyer_moore.hpp) is this:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT (( boost::is_same<
                       typename std::iterator_traits<patIter>::value_type, 
                       typename std::iterator_traits<corpusIter>::value_type>::value ));
```

This requires the value types of the iterator for the pattern and the iterator for the corpus to be the same type. In other words, you'll need to use `casechar` for the pattern as well.

Here's what I'd do:

- Write a `casechar`, with custom `operator ==` etc for case-insensitive comparison.
- No need to write a custom iterator. `const casechar *` is a perfectly acceptable random access iterator.
- Write a `std::hash<casechar>` specialization. This specialization should probably simply return something like `std::hash<char>()(std::tolower(ch))`.

That said, I'm somewhat doubtful that this will actually net you a performance gain, compared to just converting everything to lower case. The skip table for `char`s uses an optimization that uses arrays instead of `unordered_map`s for faster indexing and fewer heap allocations. This optimization is not used for a custom type such as `casechar`.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I can't convert the haystack to lower case -- it's read-only, and HUGE (I'm mapping multi-gigabyte files into memory and looking for strings in them).
If I could figure out how to provide the skip table, I think I could get the BM speed (you're right that if BM uses the unordered map, it'll probably be too slow).
Alternatively, I guess I could just implement BM myself -- it's not that hard, and if I hadn't started in on the template stuff, I'd probably be done already!

Comment: [grumble, grumble] Boost checks both the size of the pattern/corpus type and whether it's integral.  So although sizeof(casechar) is 1 (and therefore the optimization would work) it doesn't seem possible to make boost::is_integral<casechar> be true.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample code here

```
std::vector<std::wstring> names;
names.push_back(L"Rahul");
names.push_back(L"John");
names.push_back(L"Alexa");
names.push_back(L"Tejas");
names.push_back(L"Alexandra");

std::vector<std::wstring> pattern;
pattern.push_back(L"Tejas");


auto itr = boost::algorithm::boyer_moore_search<std::vector<std::wstring>,
    std::vector<std::wstring>>(names, pattern);

if (itr != names.end())
{
    OutputDebugString(std::wstring(L"pattern found in the names " + *itr).c_str());
}
else
{
    OutputDebugString(std::wstring(L"pattern not found in the names").c_str());
}
```

For the working demo of code i have created a video, please check at :

[Boyer moore search | Boost api | C++ tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3mTLf_9cEE)